# Configuration Information in Continuous Delivery

Tags: configuration, continuous-delivery

What is meant by "Configuration Information in the book "Continuous Delivery" by Jez Humble?

Answer (score 2):

Any parameter to any application that can vary across environments.  Usernames, passwords, URLs, options and flags.. anything like that.

Humble and Farley recommend (require, even!) that all configuration information be versioned in your SCM and deployed with the application it configures.  This avoids problems like default configurations that don't work, regressions caused by overwriting configuration files during deployment, or accidentally accessing production databases when deploying to a test environment.

Answer (score 0):

While it is recommended to have continuous information in an SCM, what I have found is that it is not always done. In such cases, you should look at monitoring these information or data such that any changes trigger a pipeline of validations as well, to ensure you are managing change across your SCM and configurations outside of SCM.